# Updating Files doesn't work with ObjectOutputStream in jar

Tags: java, netbeans

I'm trying to update files .ser :
Here's a snippet, without all useless stuffs (try ...etc)

```
String file1 = "data.ser";
InputStream fis = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream(file1);
InputStream buffer = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(buffer)
ArrayList<Object[]> list = new ArrayList<>();
list = (ArrayList) ois.readObject();
//Reading works fine, I got all my data in list
/*
Some operations in list
*/
OutputStream fout;
fout = new FileOutputStream(file1);
ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file1));
//Here I tried to verify list; it's okay, all is there
oos.writeObject(list);
//I tried also some print just after that, and it works
```

This doesn't update my file; what can be the trouble?
PS: on IDE, all is fine, but when running jar, it's not; is that possible that I can't change files in jar ?!

Comment: Where is your data.ser file?

Comment: Initially, an empty file placed in the same path of my classes ! I created it with Netbeans: New -> Empty File

Comment: OK if its in class path outside the jar, it should have been updated. Can you try closing all your input streams before attempting to write?

Comment: Sorry? I don't understand ... If I placed it in src/sga/facturation; and my classes are in the same location, this means I'll not getting it inside the jar?

Comment: Did you inspect your jar file? Is the data.ser file inside jar? If yes, you won't be able to modify that. You can modify if the file is outside the jar file and in classpath

Comment: Ok now I get, I have files inside jar, so I can't modify it, so .. ? should I place'em in another location like "lib" which contains a library.jar that I need.
I'm not so strong about files and all, can you give the path of the file "data.ser" if I hold it in "lib" folder?

Comment: lib folder is meant to contain all the libraries (jar files). If you don't have any suitable output directory already, create one and add the path to the classpath

Comment: Ok, thanks for the help.